# Insert data in a table in another schema from a materialized view using a procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I've been trying to insert data from a materialized view into a table that belongs to a different scheme using a procedure, but when I compile the procedure I get the error of: table or view doesn't exist. I have checked and I have selection and insertion privileges on that table. `create or replace PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_MYPROCEDURE AS 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO SCHEME.TABLE
  (COLUMN1,COLUM2)
SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2
FROM MATERIALIZED_VIEW;
END PROCEDURE_MYPROCEDURE;`

this line `SCHEME.TABLE`shows the message "PL/SQL: STATEMENT IGNORED", "TABLE OR VIEW DOES NOT EXIST"

Comment: Is your table actually called "table"? I'm not sure that's actually possible, but it would likely cause problems.

Comment: @eaolson It is for informational purposes only. The table is not called that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely cause is that you have access via a role not directly, which means you can run it in SQL but for a PLSQL procedure you need a direct privilege granted.

As per the Application Developer guide:

*Privileges Required to Create Procedures and Functions
To create a stand-alone procedure or function, or package specification or
body, you must meet the following prerequisites:
You must have the CREATE PROCEDURE system privilege to create a
procedure or package in your schema, or the CREATE ANY
PROCEDURE system privilege to create a procedure or package in
another user’s schema.
Attention: To create without errors, that is, to compile the procedure
or package successfully, requires the following additional privileges:
The owner of the procedure or package must have been explicitly
granted the necessary object privileges for all objects referenced within
the body of the code; the owner cannot have obtained required
privileges through roles.
If the privileges of a procedure’s or package’s owner change, the procedure
must be reauthenticated before it is executed. If a necessary privilege to a
referenced object is revoked from the owner of the procedure (or package), the
procedure cannot be executed.*

An easy way to test things is:

```
SQL> set role none;
SQL> "statement you want to test to see if it'll work in a procedure"
```

So you might just be missing some direct grants on those objects.

Answer (score 0):

If the procedure is compiled on user a and the MATERIALIZED_VIEW is owned by user b. When you execute the procedure it will look for the materialized view on user a.

Put the user/schema in front of the MATERIALIZED_VIEW.
You would also need to grant select on MATERIALIZED_VIEW to user a.